# (C++) Do different functions need assignment while others do not?

Tags: c++, function, substr, push-back

Can someone clarify/correct me on why certain functions such as push_back() do not need an assignment to output the new string, while a function such as substr() needs to be assigned to a string in order for the output to be the new subs-string?
For example:

```
string givenInput;
char addChar;

getline(cin, givenInput);
cin >> addChar;

givenInput.push_back(addChar);

cout << givenInput << endl;
```

This example outputs the new string without having to do `givenInput = givenInput.push_back(addChar);`. However, when doing something like:

```
string strVal;
int beginIndex;
int selectionLen;

getline(cin, strVal);
cin >> beginIndex;
cin >> selectionLen;

strVal = strVal.substr(beginIndex, selectionLen);

cout << strVal << endl;
```

Why is that I need to assign strVal rather than simply having the line `strVal.substr(beginIndex, selectionLen);` and then outputting cout << strVal?

I hope what I'm asking makes sense, and if anyone could clarify why this is, that would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: All functions return `void` if they return nothing or the function returns a value.  Nothing more, nothing less.  *You could say that `main` is a special case that doesn't need to return a value.*

Comment: You should just refer to the documentation for any given function to see what it does.  It wouldn't make sense (to me) for `substr` to behave as you describe - as implemented you can use the result for whatever purpose you choose without destroying the original string.

Comment: I was at a shop where most of the functions, that didn't need to return a value, always returned 0; and the return value wasn't used (assigned).

Comment: `substr` is specially designed to get a part of the string without destroying the original. If you instead just want to modify `strVal`, you can use the `erase` member to remove the unwanted parts.

Answer (score 3):

Those are two different styles of method.  Some methods, like [std::string::push_back()](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/) modify the object they are called upon.  Other methods, like [std::string::substr()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), do not modify the object they are called upon, but rather create a new `std::string` object and return it.  It's up the person/committee implementing a class to decide which style(s) of method they want to provide.

In order to find out what each method does, you need to read its documentation; however, in this case, a very good hint that a method does **not** modify the object that it is called upon is the presence of a `const` keyword at the end up the method's signature, like this:

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0, size_type count = npos ) const;  <-- note const keyword at end!
```

That `const` keyword at the end is basically a promise that the compiler will not allow this method to modify the object it is called upon (caveat:  the method's implemention could "cheat" and use the `const_cast<>` or `mutable` keywords to modify it anyway, but we'll ignore that possibility for now since most coders know better than to do that without a really compelling reason).